# Drawing from multiple vertex buffers in DirectX 11 with SharpDX

Tags: c#, buffer, directx-11, sharpdx, vertex-buffer

**1) The problem**

I want to draw a graph with loads of points. The dataset is not static and the points are flowing. Currently I store the graph in vertex buffer and add new points as soon as they appear. The problem is when buffer runs out of space. Maybe at the moment I pass too much data to the buffer but the max size I can set it to is

```
   int buffer_size = 1215 * (Utilities.SizeOf<Vector4>() 
                           + Utilities.SizeOf<Vector4>() 
                           + Utilities.SizeOf<Vector2>());
```

which is equal **48 600**.

For *48 640* I get an error

```
A first chance exception of type 
'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in SharpDX.Direct3D11.dll
Additional information: There was try to read or write to/from protected memory
```

My idea was to create two Vertex Buffers, and if one gets full write to the second one, still plotting both of them. The writing would be with flag **MapMode.WriteNoOverwrite**. If the second one gets full then write to the first cell of the first one with a flag **MapMode.WriteDiscard**, which will basically clear the buffer.

**2) The question:**

How to write from multiple vertex buffers?

**3) Existing code**

I set a layout with information for two slots:

```
var layout = new InputLayout(device, passSignature, new InputElement[]
    {
      new InputElement("POSITION", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 0, 0)
     ,new InputElement("COLOR", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float
                              , InputElement.AppendAligned, 0)
     ,new InputElement("TEXCOORD", 0, Format.R32G32_Float
                              , InputElement.AppendAligned, 0)

     // semantic index had also to be increased as has a slot number
     ,new InputElement("POSITION",1, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 0, 1)
     ,new InputElement("COLOR", 1, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float  
                              , InputElement.AppendAligned, 1)
     ,new InputElement("TEXCOORD", 1, Format.R32G32_Float
                                 , InputElement.AppendAligned, 1)
    });
```

Create buffers' data and set vertex buffers.

```
    float[] buffer_data = new float[] {
          -1.0f,   0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f
         , 0.2f,  -0.4f,  0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f 
         ......

    var vertices = Buffer.Create(device
                                    , BindFlags.VertexBuffer
                                    , buffer_data
                                    , buffer_size
                                    , ResourceUsage.Dynamic
                                    , CpuAccessFlags.Write
                                    , ResourceOptionFlags.None
                                    , 0);

    context.InputAssembler.InputLayout = layout;
    context.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.LineList;
    context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(
                         0
                       , new Buffer[] { vertices, vertices2 }
                       , new int[] { 40, 40 }
                       , new int[] {  0,  0 }
    );
```

Drawing

```
int sectionsToDraw = 32;
context.ClearRenderTargetView(renderView, Color.Black);

// Main loop            
RenderLoop.Run(form, () =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < technique.Description.PassCount; ++i)
    {
        pass.Apply(context);
        context.PixelShader.SetShaderResource(0, textureView);
        context.GeometryShader.SetConstantBuffer(0, _constantBuffer);
        context.Draw(sectionsToDraw,0);  
    }
    swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
});
```

and my shader's structs

```
struct VS_IN 
{
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float4 col : COLOR;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD;
};

struct GS_IN
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 col : COLOR;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD;
};

struct PS_IN
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 col : COLOR;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD;
};
```

**I do not know how to draw from the 1st slot. It only draws from the buffer in slot 1.**

The problem is not in:
- the correct set up of points to draw in both buffers
- the number of vertices to draw passed to contect.Draw in first argument
- I also tried changing shader's structs to use POSITION1 or COLOR1, but it did not help, but maybe I did not do it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to draw from two Vertex Buffers by simply switching buffers in InputAssambler in the render function

```
VertexBufferBinding vb = new VertexBufferBinding(vertices
                         , Utilities.SizeOf<Vector4>() 
                         + Utilities.SizeOf<Vector4>() 
                         + Utilities.SizeOf<Vector2>()
                         , 0);

VertexBufferBinding vb2 = new VertexBufferBinding(vertices2
                         , Utilities.SizeOf<Vector4>() 
                         + Utilities.SizeOf<Vector4>() 
                         + Utilities.SizeOf<Vector2>()
                         , 0);
```

Then in render loop

```
RenderLoop.Run(form, () =>
{
   context.ClearRenderTargetView(renderView, Color.Black);  
   .... 
   context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, vb);                              
   context.Draw(sectionsToDraw,0);
   context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, vb2);
   context.Draw(sectionsToDraw, 0);
   ....
}
```

Of course, with this solution also the layout can be simplified

```
var layout = new InputLayout(device, passSignature, new InputElement[]
    {
      new InputElement("POSITION", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 0, 0)
     ,new InputElement("COLOR",    0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float
                              , InputElement.AppendAligned, 0)
     ,new InputElement("TEXCOORD", 0, Format.R32G32_Float
                              , InputElement.AppendAligned, 0)
    }
```

but now, I am not sure if my solution does not involve copying the whole buffer every draw call. I have to read about it a bit more.

What I think is my problem is that I am using Directx 11, and I cannot find a partial Lock for buffer, like the one as I understand was in Directx 9. http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-direct3d9-vertexbuffer-lock It looks like there is none in DirectX 11. I found that you can take **MapSubresource** of a resource, but according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) "A buffer is defined as a single subresource". So, it is not possible to lock only a part of a buffer as I would like to.